# How to connect to Quickbooks premier desktop edition through qbxmlrp using java?

Tags: quickbooks

I have installed a quickbooks premier 2014 desktop edition in my system and wants to integrate it using QBXML Request processor API(QBXMLRP2) through java application.

I have gone through the QBXML SDK Documentation but didn't find a proper way on integration with java. 
 I found this from the documentation :

```
  1.Open a connection to QuickBooks.
  2.Start a session for working on a specific QuickBooks company file.
  3.Send whatever requests you want to do something in QuickBooks.
  4.When you’re done or before your application exits, end the session.
  5.Then close the connection.
```

It will be greatly appreciated if some one could provide me some sample code to integrate with Quickbooks.

And also how to configure QBXMLRP2Lib files in my java application?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a proper way? I have same requirement

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called [QuickBooks Web Connector](http://marketplace.intuit.com/webconnector/) that allows your app to use QBXML through a web service.  Intuit has created a [sample java application that communicates with web connector](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/samples/readme.html#QBWebConnectorSvc%20%28Java%29%20%28qbxml%29%20%28desktop%29) that may provide what you need.

Also, if you're starting a new app from scratch you may want to consider using the newer "V3 QBD" API instead of QBXML.

Comment: Thanks @OffTheRader for your response.I have gone through it but web connector will not suit for my requirement.I appreciate your help.

Comment: I found a link [QBbridge](https://intuitcorp.quickbase.com/db/7mm4jb62?a=q&qid=1) which will provide a bridge between Quickbooks desktop and java application.I'm able to connect with Quickbooks Desktop with the sample dll file(sdkjcalls.dll) that they have provided but it is only working with default package.If I add this dll file other than default package(in eclipse) it is not working.Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.qbd.RequestProcessor.openConnectionInternal(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V.Can any one please help on this.

Comment: sayagoud, might wanna play with setting up the native library path for java